# Setting primary key on stages

Tags: sql-server

My table is big 3M records with long text fields in it.

I am trying to set primary key on one of the numeric columns.

It is taking so long and I had to restart the server several times and restart all over again

is there a way i can do this on stages?

e.g. for 100,000 records at each stage

or indexing the column or any other way?

**Edit:**

This is a training dataset I got from the internet on my personal computer. not for business.

Comment: *"is there a way i can do this on stages?"* No, the DBMS will need to scan the entire table to check the column(s) is unique to create the `PRIMARY KEY`. It does seem odd that you are adding this PK *after* you've inserted 3 Million rows; normally you would create the PK before.

Comment: Why did you have to restart the server several times?

Comment: @Larnu this is a training data set i got from the internet on my home computer. not for business.

Comment: That dosen't mean you can't create the dataset table, with the PK. and then `INSERT` the data.

Comment: @Larnu too late, I already created the table and has all data in there.

Comment: Then you'll have to wait... @asmgx . Order of operations is important. You'll probably be better off creating a new table, with a PK, and then inserting all the data into the new one; then dropping the old one and renaming the neww one.